# how to change remote fetch url in git

Tags: git, git-remote, git-fetch

My git remote repo looks like this:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/dolphin-scripts.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/dolphin-scripts.git (push)
origin  https://gitee.com/jiangxiaoqiang/dolphin-scripts.git (push)
```

now I want fetch from *gitee* by default, how to change the fetch url to *gitee*?

Comment: Look at this [tutorial](https://support.beanstalkapp.com/article/1001-how-do-i-change-git-remote-url)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
git remote add origin https://gitee.com/jiangxiaoqiang/dolphin-scripts.git --mirror=fetchde here
```

if you already have origin you may have to clean up the remote names and readd (3 commands):

```
git remote origin remove
git remote add origin https://gitee.com/jiangxiaoqiang/dolphin-scripts.git
git remote set-url --push origin https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/dolphin-scripts.git
```

Comment: not works.`$ git remote add origin https://gitee.com/jiangxiaoqiang/dolphin-scripts.git --mirror=fetch
fatal: remote origin already exists.` @Json Phillips

Comment: You may have to remove origin first then add it again ie
git remote remove origin

Comment: Hello @Jason, it is not adviced to use a `--push` URL separately. It is better to create a separate remote for pushing/fetching to support triangular workflows

Answer (score 2):

As @Jason Phillips says, you have to first do:

```
git remote remove origin
```

which will remove the origin remote and the URLs associated with it. Next you do:

```
git remote add origin https://gitee.com/jiangxiaoqiang/dolphin-scripts.git
```

which will add a new remote called `origin` associated with the `gitee` URL.
Now you add another remote (let's call it `extra`) which will be used to push to GitHub

```
git remote add extra https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/dolphin-scripts.git
```

Now you may do a `git push extra` to push to GitHub and `git fetch origin` or `git pull origin` to fetch and pull changes from `Gitee` respectively.

Best